# How to add product tabs dynamically in magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0, product-tab

I am used this plugin but is not working in magento 2.3.0
di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details"> 
     <plugin name="vendor_product_view_description" type="Vendor\ProductTab\Plugin\Description" /> 
</type>
```

````
namespace Vendor\ProductTab\Plugin;
use Vendor\ProductTab\Model\TabConfig;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Details;
class Description
{

    private $tabs;
    public function __construct(
        TabConfig $tabs
    )
    {
        $this->tabs = $tabs;
    }
    public function afterGetGroupSortedChildNames(
        Details $subject,
        $result
    )
    {
        if (!empty($this->tabs->getTabs())) {
            foreach ($this->tabs->getTabs() as $key => $tab) {
                $sortOrder = isset($tab['position']) ? $tab['position'] : 40;
                $result = array_merge($result, [$sortOrder => 'product.info.details.' . $key]);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}```
````

Comment: you want to tab add in luma theme or custom theme?

Comment: @rakeshdonga `luma theme`

Comment: you can write code here properly so i will check it

Comment: @RakeshDonga please check updated question.